# how node.js xpress server can get remote file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I am building node.js server and client , the client needs to send an **url** to a local file like this: `C:\Users\Pictures\Capture.PNG` and the server needs to get that file only using the sent **url** from the user.
I have seen to many solutions to this issue but all of them use `http` and that does not work for me, I do not want to use `scp` or `ssh` , how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to read the file locally?

```
fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Capture.PNG', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     // Send data back in the response here...
});
```

Comment: no, the remote server needs to get an url and access remote file system using http if that is possible..

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it isn't possible for a piece of software on one computer to get a file from another computer knowing nothing about it other than a local file path.

The usual way to solve this problem would be for the client to send the *file* and not the local file path. This can be done using a `<input type="file">` in a form.

Comment: I do not need to use forms :)

Comment: is that possible using http?!

Comment: HTTP is mandatory for this approach. HTML forms only work over HTTP. Express is an HTTP server.

Comment: okay, so how can remote server send http request and access local file in the client?, but not to use forms in order to upload data to the server..

Comment: You can't make an HTTP request to a client. You can only make one to a server. Have the client send the file in the request to the server in the first place.

Comment: that what I should not do, I need the server to be responsible of the process of getting the file not the client.